# Efficient uint512 divide by uint512 algorithm in Solidity

Tags: solidity

Like how Remco created an efficient uint512 divide by uint256 algorithm in Solidity [512 bit division](https://xn--2-umb.com/17/512-bit-division/index.html). I am wondering if there is an efficient uint512 divide by uint512 algorithm. If not, is there an idea on how to do so?